# Show values from array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, the title might make it sound easy (and maybe it is), but I can't figure out how to show values from an array, not just do a *each* with them, but put them on the site slowly, with a nice effect...

Like this [Twitter widget](https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_search), but from an array (maybe wait 2sec, and when throw another value from the array)?

My array contains another array, with 4 values, is it possible to show the first 2 values, wait about 2 sec, and then show the last 2 values? Now when the last two values is out (from the prev array), wait 2 more seconds, and show the next array (again with four values, first show 2, wait 2 sec, and show the next 2, and so on...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily using `setInterval` or a chained series of `setTimeout`. I tend to prefer the latter, which looks something like this:

```
function showValues(a, delay) {
    var index = 0;

    if (a.length !== 0) {
        // If you want a delay before the first one:
        setTimeout(showValue, delay);

        // Alternately, if you want to show the first right away
        // showValue();
    }

    // Function to show one value
    function showValue() {
        // Get the value
        var value = a[index++];

        /* ...show the value however you see fit... */

        // Schedule next display, if any
        if (index < a.length) {
            // Schedule next run
            setTimeout(showValue, delay);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
showValues(["value1", "value2", /* etc. */, 2000); 2000 = two seconds
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/osofux) | [source](http://jsbin.com/osofux/edit)

Comment: @Moiblpadde: It's just an extension of the same technique.

Comment: Awesome! Figured it out :D
I feel kinda stupid right now D: (Was pretty simple through, once I took a look at the code :3)
[Final code](http://jsbin.com/iwucex/2/edit#source)

Comment: @Moiblpadde: Good deal! Glad that helped.

Answer (score 4):

Animation functions like `fadeIn()` make use of the jQuery FX queue so you can use `.delay()` in the call chain to delay the calling of these functions. In the following example one element is shown every second.

```
var data = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'moo', 'meow', 'xxx'];
var list = $('ul');
$.each(data, function(i, value) {
    $('<li/>', { text: value }).hide().appendTo(list).delay(i * 1000).fadeIn();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/frW8s/